# All my vmplayer virtual machines are 'busy' after upgrade in Linux

Tags: linux, vmware-player, slackware

I upgraded from `Slackware64 13.37` to `current` (pretty close to the new version 14.0 - kernel 3.2.29) and installed `vmplayer` 5.0.0 build-812388.

The installation of `vmplayer` was only possible with the `--ignore-errors` option, like the previous version.

But unlike the previou version (working fine), when I try to play any of my `.vmx`  images, I always get a 'The virtual machine is busy.' error.

In the windows client directory, `vmplayer` creates a `lck` directory with a `.lck` lock file in there.

Removing this file doesn't solve the issue.  If I don't remove this file and try to run the virtual machine again, `vmplayer` exits.

When running from command line, I get this:

```
$ vmplayer Windows_7.vmx    
Logging to /tmp/vmware-lupe/vmware-modconfig-24735.log
filename:       /lib/modules/3.2.29/misc/vmmon.ko
supported:      external
license:        GPL v2
description:    VMware Virtual Machine Monitor.
author:         VMware, Inc.
depends:       
vermagic:       3.2.29 SMP mod_unload
Aborted
```

The log file mentioned above:

```
2012-09-26T16:53:01.299Z| vthread-3| I120: Log for VMware Workstation pid=24735 version=9.0.0 build=build-812388 option=Release
2012-09-26T16:53:01.299Z| vthread-3| I120: The process is 64-bit.
2012-09-26T16:53:01.299Z| vthread-3| I120: Host codepage=ISO-8859-1 encoding=ISO-8859-1
2012-09-26T16:53:01.299Z| vthread-3| I120: Host is Linux 3.2.29 Slackware 14.0
2012-09-26T16:53:01.298Z| vthread-3| I120: Msg_Reset:
2012-09-26T16:53:01.298Z| vthread-3| I120: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2012-09-26T16:53:01.298Z| vthread-3| I120: ----------------------------------------
2012-09-26T16:53:01.298Z| vthread-3| I120: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /usr/lib/vmware/settings. Using default values.
2012-09-26T16:53:01.298Z| vthread-3| I120: Msg_Reset:
2012-09-26T16:53:01.298Z| vthread-3| I120: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/home/lupe/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2012-09-26T16:53:01.298Z| vthread-3| I120: ----------------------------------------
2012-09-26T16:53:01.298Z| vthread-3| I120: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /home/lupe/.vmware/config. Using default values.
2012-09-26T16:53:01.299Z| vthread-3| W110: Logging to /tmp/vmware-lupe/vmware-modconfig-24735.log
2012-09-26T16:53:01.307Z| vthread-3| I120: Reading in info for the vmmon module.
2012-09-26T16:53:01.307Z| vthread-3| I120: Reading in info for the vmnet module.
2012-09-26T16:53:01.307Z| vthread-3| I120: Reading in info for the vmblock module.
2012-09-26T16:53:01.307Z| vthread-3| I120: Reading in info for the vmci module.
2012-09-26T16:53:01.307Z| vthread-3| I120: Reading in info for the vsock module.
2012-09-26T16:53:01.307Z| vthread-3| I120: Setting vsock to depend on vmci.
2012-09-26T16:53:01.307Z| vthread-3| I120: Created new pathsHash.
2012-09-26T16:53:01.307Z| vthread-3| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2012-09-26T16:53:01.309Z| vthread-3| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 0.
2012-09-26T16:53:01.309Z| vthread-3| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2012-09-26T16:53:01.311Z| vthread-3| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 0.
2012-09-26T16:53:01.311Z| vthread-3| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vmblock".
2012-09-26T16:53:01.312Z| vthread-3| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 0.
2012-09-26T16:53:01.312Z| vthread-3| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vmci".
2012-09-26T16:53:01.314Z| vthread-3| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 0.
2012-09-26T16:53:01.314Z| vthread-3| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vsock".
2012-09-26T16:53:01.315Z| vthread-3| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 0.
```

It complains about a settings and a config file missing but is loading default values.

I don't see anything more that can hint me on what to do.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone pointed out in vmware's forum, it is necessary to manually install the modules again:

```
vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

This solves the problem.